# Solve the differential equation $\frac {du}{dx} \times \frac {du}{dy}= 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I saw this problem and I am not sure how should I start to solve it. Could you please help me with some hints?

Solve the following equation for functions u ∈ $C^2(R^2, R)$

$d_{1}u \times d_{2}u=0$

I know that one or both of them should be zero, meaning it is a constant but I am clueless about how can I use it.

Answer (score 4):

Some more information about what the question is asking would be useful.

Are you solving for $u$?

What is $u$ a function of?

If $u$ is a function of $x$ and $y$, then perhaps the equation should read $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Unfortunely, I don't have enough reputation to comment yet.

Comment: Let me contribute to your reputation by the upvote :D

Comment: @AbhijeetVats Thankyou much appreciated!

Comment: @iCaird (+1) for contribution:)

Comment: Thanks to those who upvoted! I can now comment everywhere so will be sure to comment stuff like this rather than answer in the future! :)

Comment: The question was: Solve the following equation for functions u ∈ C^2(R^2, R) ∂1u · ∂2u = 0

Comment: I edited the question